Speech-to-text functionality functions properly in the local environment but encounters network issues in the client's environment
Speech-to-text functions smoothly in the local environment but faces network errors in the azure virtual desktop. I've verified all browser permissions, and everything appears to be in order. If anyone else is experiencing a similar issue, any solutions would be greatly appreciated.
my code is:
let recognition;
let isListening = false;
    function toggleSpeechRecognition() {
        if (!isListening) {
            startSpeechRecognition();
        } else {
            endSpeechRecognition();
        }
    }

    function startSpeechRecognition() {
        if (!recognition) {
            if ('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) {
                recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
            } else if ('SpeechRecognition' in window) {
                recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
            } else {
                return;
            }

            recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                const transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                document.getElementById("chatInput").value = transcript;
            };

            recognition.onerror = function(event) {
                console.error('Speech recognition error:', event.error);
            };

            recognition.onend = function() {
                document.getElementById('mic_icon').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById('soundwave_icon').style.display = 'none';
                var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('span-s');
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = '#008d81';
                }
                isListening = false;
            };
        }
        document.getElementById('mic_icon').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('soundwave_icon').style.display = 'inline';
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('span-s');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }

        recognition.start();
        isListening = true;
    }

    function endSpeechRecognition() {
        if (recognition) {
            recognition.stop();
        }

        document.getElementById('mic_icon').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('soundwave_icon').style.display = 'none';
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('span-s');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].style.backgroundColor = '#008d81';
        }
        isListening = false;
    }
    document.getElementById('soundwave_icon').addEventListener('click', function() {
        endSpeechRecognition();
    });

I've checked all browser permissions to ensure they're configured correctly. Additionally, I've reviewed network settings and tested connectivity to rule out any issues on that front. However, the problem persists. I was expecting the speech-to-text feature to work smoothly in the client's environment as it does in the local environment. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has suggestions for troubleshooting steps, I would greatly appreciate the assistance.

What is the exact error you are facing?

Hi Jayashankar G S, thanks for for your concern. In this line I am catching event error (console.error('Speech recognition error:', event.error);).Here I am getting
Speech recognition error: network
